# Problems with SonarQube plugin development

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to develop a sonar plugin which will generate a report on post job.

Initially I started with sonarqube 5.0.1 and sonar api 4.5.1. I used the web service api to develop the plugin. But sonarqube threw 500 internal exception during every sonar analysis. On some debugging I understood, because I am making many calls sonarqube threw that error. Then I added some delay and retry logic between every call and it started working fine.

Upon further investigation I came to know that SensorContext has a method named getMeasure. Then I replaced the web service calls with getMeasure calls. Everything worked fine until I tried to get sqale_index. The value returned by the api was a double number. But I wanted it in the hours/days format. Then I googled how to convert it and I came out know that I have to use a formula. I used sqale formula but it did not match with the value returned by the web service api. So again I went back to use the web service api.

In a hope that newer versions of sonarqube and sonar api will resolve my problem I switched to sonarqube 5.4 and sonar api 5.3.

As a trial I ran my plugin using the new versions and I came to know getMeasure calls won't work and throw exceptions at runtime because in 5.3 getMeasure is deprecated and should sensors should only save data not read data.

Then I thought to use decorators and since 5.2 they are also deprecated. So I again went back to use web service api irrespective of the sonarqube version or sonar api version. I ran the analysis on my code base and I got 500 internal exceptions on most of the web service calls despite adding more delay and more retrys.

Now I am fed up and have no idea how to develop the plugin. I do not know why sonarqube team is deprecating everything and they completely forgot the meaning of deprecation in java.

Can anyone please help me how to get rid of the 500 internal exceptions or how to get metric details from sonar api.

Thank you.

Comment: try asking for help on the Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

Comment: Thank you. I will give a try there. Is that an official sonarqube forum?

Comment: It is. (stupid minimum comment length!)